# How to return HashMap from Java 8 orElse/orElseGet operator

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I am trying to return HashMap from the orElse/orElseGet stream operator but it seems not able to use the HashMap in these operator.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) {

        List<String> names = new ArrayList<String>() {{
            add("test1");
        }};

        HashMap<Integer, String> indexToNameMap = names.stream()
                .filter(name -> name.equals("test"))
                .map(name -> new HashMap<Integer, String>() {{
                    put(names.indexOf(name), name);
                }})
                .findFirst()
                .orElseGet(() -> new HashMap<Integer, String>() {{
                    put(0, "UN_AVAILABLE");
                }});
    }
}
```

Error:

```
Bad return type in lambda expression: HashMap<Integer, String> cannot be converted to HashMap<Integer, String>
```

How to fix this issue?

Comment: Not really connected to the question but [Don’t be “Clever” - don't use double braces initialisation](https://blog.jooq.org/2014/12/08/dont-be-clever-the-double-curly-braces-anti-pattern/) **Edit**: actually it is connected to the issue in here.

Comment: Apart from the question, is there a real use case of creating `HashMap`s for every filtered entry with the same `name`  and then finding the first out of them? Are you sure you don't want to perform `contains` somehow? Also, you can rather look into the `counting` implementation of `Collector` and make use of it if the actual use case is directed that way.

Comment: Also: using `AtomicInteger.incrementAndGet()` seems ill-advised here. A `Map<Integer, String>` which you intend to have consecutive keys is effectively a `List<String>`.

Comment: Why not just `Collections.singletonMap(index, name)`? On, in newer version, `Map.of(index, name)`?

Comment: @AndyTurner, his index wil always be equal to either `1` or `0` with this code. He'll not be through with this that easy :)

Comment: @seenimurugan, OP, seems like you just want the `names.indexOf("test")`. What's the point in writing code that complex?

Comment: @M.Prokhorov Million thanks. Updated the code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This:

```
        .map(name -> new HashMap<Integer, String>() {{
            put(index.incrementAndGet(), name);
        }})
```

is creating an anonymous subclass of `HashMap` - and that's the actual type of the stream after this stage. It's something like a `Stream<YourClass$1>` after this point.

As such, your `orElseGet` has to return something of the same type (or a subclass) - which it can't, because the map has returned an anonymous type, and that can't be accessed elsewhere in the code.

The smallest change would be to cast:

```
    .map(name -> (HashMap<Integer, String>) new HashMap<Integer, String>() {{
        put(index.incrementAndGet(), name);
    }})
```

but that's quite verbose; and double-brace initialization is gross anyway. Either use `Collections.singletonMap`:

```
        .map(name -> Collections.singletonMap(index.incrementAndGet(), name))
```

or just write it without the anonymous class, as a statement lambda:

```
        .map(name -> {
            HashMap<Integer, String> map = new HashMap<>();
            map.put(index.incrementAndGet(), name);
            return map;
        })
```

Comment: Thank you @AndyTurner. You are a star.

Comment: I am now using Map.of(names::indexOf, name)

Answer (score 3):

Here:

```
.orElseGet(() -> new HashMap<Integer, String>() {{put(0, "UN_AVAILABLE");}})
```

You are mixing syntax elements badly here. You probably had in mind:

```
new HashMap<>() { 
  { put(0, "whatever"); }
}
```

In other words: an anonymous inner class of HashMap, that has an initializer block that adds a member. Simply: don't do that (not here, not in any code). Whilst this *works*, it is considered bad practice by most people.

Instead, put things into the lambda body directly:

```
() -> {
  HashMap<Integer, String> rv = new HashMap<>();
  rv.put(....)
  return rv;
}
```

Comment: Sure. Thank you.

Comment: "You probably had in mind:" I disagree: this likely *isn't* what OP had in mind, even if it is what was effectively written. I think what OP had in mind was "this is a neat way to create and populate a HashMap", without realising the dark side of the syntactic bodge that is double-brace initialization :)

Comment: Yes, you are correct @AndyTurner. I was not aware of the dark side of the double-brace initialization.

Answer (score 3):

To makes things clearer, just declare a `BiFunction<Integer, String, HashMap<Integer, String>>`   that creates the Map and initializes it with a specify entry :

```
final BiFunction<Integer, String, HashMap<Integer, String>>  newHashMap = 
(k, v) ->{
   HashMap<Integer, String> map = new HashMap<>(); 
   map.put(k, v);
   return map;
}

HashMap<Integer, String> indexToNameMap = names.stream()
            .filter(name -> name.equals("test"))
            .map(name -> newHashMap.apply(index.incrementAndGet(), name))
            .findFirst()
            .orElseGet(() -> newHashMap.apply(0,  "UN_AVAILABLE"))
```

Comment: Does this really make it clearer? `Collections.singletonMap` would achieve largely the same, without the BiFunction declaration.

Comment: @Andy Turner Much clearer that the two initializers. Compare things that are comparable. Note also that `singletonMap()` returns an immutable map. That is not a requirement of this question. It could even a limitation.

Comment: then use `new HashMap<>(singletonMap(...))`.

Comment: @Andy Turner  Besides, you will make it twice (for each HashMap) or else you will have  asymmetric HashMap instantiations. And you find it clearer as approach ? Me no.

Comment: then write it as a "real" method. Declaring and initializing variables with explicit functional types should only be done rarely.

Comment: @Andy Turner why do you think that ? I though (maybe I am wrong, tell me) that declaring a function in the scope of the current method was a better approach than declaring it as a private method because it allows to set the minimal scope required and it also sets close/together the function and the code that uses that. What is the disadvantage of this approach for you ?

Comment: 1) it's jarring to read. The `BiFunction<...>` is cruft that adds little value. 2) the return type coming after the parameter types is cognitive burden, vs every other method you write in Java. 3) if you only ever use it by calling the apply method (as opposed to passing it to a method that requires a BiFunction), you lose the benefit of it being a functional type. It may as well be a method, and save writing the `.apply`. Just about the only benefit I can see to using a functional variable is scope; for something that just creates a simple thing, doesn't use any state from the...

Comment: ...surrounding scope etc, I would not be overly concerned with that being accessible outside the method. But really: `new HashMap<>(singletonMap(key, value))` is fine way to write it (the overhead of creating the singleton map is basically irrelevant, to the point that the JVM may not even create it).

Comment: @Andy Turner Thanks for your inputs. I agree for disadvantages you quote in the 2 first points , less for the third : here I don't seek the functional interface feature, which matters is the proximity between the code that uses it and the function : reduced scope and no reading indirection. I would also add that with this way, not need to scroll code to understand the logic. And even in the time.  For example, the introduction of a new method could make the private method be moved away Here it will not be the case.

Comment: ... I think that the two first drawbacks are related to the Java verbosity. Just for the record in Scala, doing it `val addFn = ((a: Int, b: Int) => a + b)` inside a function is not rare. And we can use it such as `addFn(1,2)`. No `apply()`, no `BiFunction`...

Comment: if you're really concerned about scope, declare the lambda as a parameter of the map: all 3 of my criticisms go away.

Comment: Not sure to understand what you mean.  Can you give me a sample please ?

Comment: see snippet in my answer, following "or just write it without the anonymous class, as a statement lambda:".

Comment: ah but in this case , two new criticisms come from me now. To  
 make it readable and clear we should do it for the 2 map instantiations. it will create some duplication and it is verbose too. Not sure that we have a really perfect solution in java for this case.